# Copy a specific column from a csv file to an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a little problem that is how to Copy a **specific column** from a **csv file**  to an **array** using **javascript**

thank you :)

Comment: What library are you using to accomplish this, or are you trying to implement it in pure JS?

Comment: Parse the CSV data into an array of arrays (rows and columns) and then use `Array#map` over the rows to extract the desired field. E.g. `rows.map(row => row[2])`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i don' care if it's in pure js or using a library ....my csv is in " c:\project\adresse.csv "                              in python for example :
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
saved_column = df.column_name
is there any solution in JS

Answer (score 0):

csv data is best represented in javascript using an array of arrays (a 2-dimension array) with primary indices representing rows (records in data-base terminology) and the inner indices representing column cells for that row (fields in data-base terminology).

Thus, this csv data:

```
"name","age","height"
"John",22,1.9
"Jane",21,1.9
"Joe",23,1.8
```

would be represented as:

`[["name","age","height"],["John",22,1.9],["Jane",21,1.9],["Joe",23,1.8]];`

in a javascript array.

If you have an array like that, you can extract a column (the first column, inner array index [0] in this case, easily with:

```
const columnArray = [];
for (let i=0; i<csvArray.length; i++){columnArray.push(array1[i][0])}
// columnArray now holds ["name","John","Jane","Jo"];
// use [1] instead of [0] for the second column, [2] for the third, etc.;
```

If you don't yet have the array, you will have to form one. Many frameworks may do this for you but it is easily achieved once you have the csv data inside a variable:

```
const csvFileData = // read from textarea or file;

const csvArray = csvFileData.split('\n')
// csvArray holds ['"name","age","height"', '"John",22,1.9', '"Jane",21,1.9', '"Joe",23,1.8'] at this stage;
 
// split the inner arrays to arrays of cell data;
for (let i=0; i<array1.lengthl; i++){array[i]=array[i].split(',')}
// We've replaced each element with an array holding the component cells of what was previously a row;

// csvArray now holds:
[["name","age","height"],["John",22,1.9],["Jane",21,1.9],["Joe",23,1.8]];
```

That final array can now be processed to extract the required column as shown above.

Finally, all this assumes you can get the csv data into a variable (remember it has line breaks). Fetch() is probably the standard way but a simple (if dirty) alternative I often use is to assign the value of an html textarea into which I have pasted the csv file contents into, directly to a variable:

```
const csvFileData = document.getElementById('textareaOnWebPage').value;
```

Comment: my csv file is in ===>  c:\project\adresse.csv  , is there any solution to read it directly without using the  "const csvFileData = document.getElementById('textareaOnWebPage').value;"

Comment: in python for example :
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
saved_column = df.column_name
is there any solution in JS

Comment: @Fares Zaalouni, different frameworks will each have their own means of accessing file data. If you're using python, search youtube for reading file data. My answer intends to give the general case achieved without any libraries or frameworks. Fetch() is the standard js means of extracting data but dealing with responses etc. is too involved to answer here (that's why I suggested loading into a variable from a textarea. If you find a premade python function to extract a column directly, it will likely be doing the steps I explained. Good luck.